# Is it possible to make AWS Cognito app client hosted UI to redirect requests to dynamic domain names for multi-tenant apps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

We use AWS Cognito for authentication in our development environments. Our problem with our current setup is that Cognito does not work on multi-tenant apps.

This is how our Cognito setup looks like:

1. User pool is created
2. The app client is created in the app integration section
3. The app client has hosted UI, which has a single entry in "Allowed callback URLs"

Our problem is that an app with a subdomain can be created from our application and we can't dynamically update the "Allowed callback URLs" list with it.

Is it possible to somehow make Cognito redirect the authenticated users back to the domain from which it received the request?

Any kind of help would be appreciated